# Visualizing word cloud changes over time?

Tags: animation, rendering, word-cloud

I'm looking for a tool that can visualize changes in a word cloud over time.

I have a database with a lot of entries and the word cloud I generated helped my team better understand the way the product is used.

But I realized that it would be even more interesting to show how the trends changed over time.

Comment: Have you loked at Google's gource or http://logstalgia.io/ ? Perhaps these tools can be modified to show repetitions of words in the wordcloud instead of git checkin activity or prevalent website traffic requests. the source is freely available.